# Unable to run OWASP dependencyCheck

Tags: gradle, owasp

Unable to run OWASP dependencyCheck and it throws the following error

- id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' version '9.0.5'

```
./gradlew dependencyCheckAnalyze
Region [NODEAUDIT] : Not alive and dispose was called, filename: NODEAUDIT
Region [CENTRAL] : Not alive and dispose was called, filename: CENTRAL
Region [POM] : Not alive and dispose was called, filename: POM
```

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: org.owasp.dependencycheck is the only plugin in the build.gradle. build.gradle is a standard Spring Boot 3.0 compliant project otherwise. I am not in a position to share the file right now

Comment: could you use another version of `owasp` like `8.x` not latest one `9.x` ?  as example `8.1.2` ?

Comment: got the same error with 8.4.3, but 8.1.2 didn't give any output. will debug this further

Comment: +    id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' version '9.0.6'
I tried with the recent version which was published yesterday, but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add `--stacktrace` (additionally `--info` or `--debug` if it's necessary) to the `gradle` cmd, in order to get more detailed information about the error's cause.

Also, since you're not sharing the `build.gradle` to see your `dependencyCheck{}` configuration, it's hard to guess what is happening.

However as far as I know, this error is related to NVD data which is not available in your environment, the most common cases I found are:

- NVD service is not available or under load, so it's not possible to download.
- You clone a project which has `dependencyCheck { autoUpdate=false }` and you're running the project for the first time. In this case simple turn `autoUpdate=true` to download the data.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue that seems to have been resolved now with an update of DependencyCheck.
See https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/6107.

Comment: Not sure if the above fix is rolled into any of the recent releases, since it didn't work with 9.0.6 as well